# What is the correct way to define a subtype in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In the following code example, the intention is that `scrapeMovies` function accepts only serializable objects.

```
/* @flow */

type SerializableObjectType = {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean | $ReadOnlyArray<SerializableObjectType> | SerializableObjectType
};

type GuideType = {|
  rid: string
|};

const guide: GuideType = {
  rid: 'foo'
};

const scrapeMovies = async (guide: SerializableObjectType) => {};

scrapeMovies(guide);
```

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKeATgJYCGMZAXhQEYx4Dy9AVngMYYAquBAXjABvVGDABtANZ4sALjABnDOQB2AcwC6C5WvVgAPmFUBXALb1ShsPThwmFVdYAkAJTwUAJs1UwsAQRISCiwAHmJyKloGJlYObj58AD5rCMpqOkYWdi5eflQAXwBudGx8MABxEzJPPETBEQMxMHJPHRUyDVQDYvROOFVlMHVq2oUqmrr+MCFRcVaFAHIoO0XCktR+wYwlTmD8AFk4ADcyPEUZsApFLFVOMAAKEcmFNKjM2JyE-gBKGZThL1UIo9hRDiczoonqM8D8ikA

I do not comprehend what is the reason [flowtype](/questions/tagged/flowtype) is complaining about `scrapeMovies` being fed `guide` object, which is less strict definition of a `SerializableObjectType`.

Whats the correct way to define a sub-type here?

Comment: Your types seem contradictory. `ScrapeMoviesGuideType` has exactly one property, while `SerializableObjectType` is a general dictionary. If you declare `guide: SerializableObjectType` for `scrapeMovies`, that means you could pass the wrong type since it only accepts `ScrapeMoviesGuideType`.

Comment: The intent is to define one general type for all scraper methods. Specific scraper methods should be able to restrict the type within the bounds of the general type. `SerializableObjectType` is a general dictionary, as you said, but `ScrapeMoviesGuideType` is a sub-type of that dictionary.

Comment: `const scrapeMovies: ScrapeMoviesType` tells Flow that the function accepts `SerializableObjectType` as an argument. All other type information  has been erased. That means you could pass any serializable object to the function, which directly contradicts the actual function definition. "Specific scraper methods should be able to restrict the type within the bounds of the general type." but how? If all it knows is that it's serializable, that's all it knows. You're essentially telling it to cast from a supertype _to_ a subtype, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Is it something thats not allowed by design or is it something that could be a desired feature?

Comment: You'd doing the same as if you did [this simple double-declaration](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKeATgJYCGMZAXhQEYx4Dy9AVngMYYAquBAXjABvVGDABtANZ4sALjABnDOQB2AcwC6C5WvVgAPmFUBXALb1ShsPThwmFVdYAkAJTwUAJs1UwsAQRISCiwAHmJyKloGJlYObj58AD5rCMpqOkYWdi5eflQAXwBudGx8Ik5g-ABZOAA3MjxFAHETMk88RMERAzEwAGpyTx0VMg1UA2L0TjhVZSVKihr6xsUASVVVKyEKRSxVTjAACnU2joVCReWGptb2zv4ASjABFOEp1Bm5jAWqvFqbooXscKCR1BdSOlolk4rkus9Xr8lv8Vk0NlsSEdQepHkUgA). You've got a function that accepts a general type, and another with a specific type. The `arg` passed to `scrapeMoviesInner` doesn't match.

Comment: It would be a bug to allow you to do what you're asking, because you've declared that `rid` must exist, and there is no code in your program to actually enforce that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a `GuideType` in place of a `SerializableObjectType` is an instance of passing a more specific type. Flow only allows [less specific](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-less-specific-inputs-good) (contravariant/write-only) inputs in functions by default.

To get this to work, you need to mark the `guide` parameter as [covariant](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-covariance). By marking the object as [`$ReadOnly<T>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-readonly), you'll effectively be marking it as covariant:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0AQ4FwTwBwU2BlGAnAlgQwDYoF5oEYYwDyeAVjAMZgAq0cAvMAN4BQooA2gNYwQBcwAM5hUAOwDmAXQHCx44AB9gogK4BbPMkXA8Ae12E0o7QBIASjDQATIqIwQAgkiRoIAHkSpMOfIRLkqWlgAPm1PdCxcAmIySho6NlAAXwBuFkSQSFhgAHEVFCsYIIZmBQzQVCsZERQJcoVU9PYKXVFhYHF8woE8gqK6YEZWdhBKgQByADN9cfLG8pa2sCEKF1gAWV0ANxQYQUHgNEEIUQpgAApOvoFzSxs7d3DvKL9YwLpggEpB0KZ59kEqzQG22u0Ely6ME+KSAA))

```
type SerializableObjectType = {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean | $ReadOnlyArray<SerializableObjectType> | SerializableObjectType
};

type GuideType = {|
  rid: string
|};

const guide: GuideType = {
  rid: 'foo'
};

const scrapeMovies = async (guide: $ReadOnly<SerializableObjectType>) => {};

scrapeMovies(guide);
```

Alternatively, you can mark [specific properties as covariant/read-only](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-covariant-read-only-properties-on-interfaces) using the `+` sign in the object type declaration:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0AQ4FwTwBwU2BlGAnAlgQwDYoF5oEYYwDyeAVjAMZgAq0cAvMAN4BQooA1ANoDWMEALmABnMKgB2AcwC6Q0RMnAAPsHEBXALZ5ky4HgD2+wmnG6AJACUYaACZFxGCAEEkSNBAA8iVJhz5CJORUtLAAfLre6Fi4BMRklDR0bKAAvgDcLMkgkLDAAOJqKDYwIQzMSlmgqDZyYihSlUrpmewU+uKiwJKFxUIFRSV0wIys7CDVQgDkAGaGk5XNlW0dYCIUbrAAsvoAbigwwsPAaMIQ4hTAABTdA0KRvjEB8cF0AJTD4UyL7MLraFu7fbCa49GCvNJAA))

```
type SerializableObjectType = {
  +[key: string]: string | number | boolean | $ReadOnlyArray<SerializableObjectType> | SerializableObjectType
};

type GuideType = {|
  rid: string
|};

const guide: GuideType = {
  rid: 'foo'
};

const scrapeMovies = async (guide: SerializableObjectType) => {};

scrapeMovies(guide);
```

Why do you have to do this dance? Why does it matter whether the input is covariant/contravariant/whateverariant? Well, if you tried to treat the `guide` parameter like a `SerializeableObjectType` (a general object map), and you wrote a `number` to the `rid` key, other consumers of that `guide` object wouldn't get what they're expecting.